# How to replace woocommerce | (pipe) separator in product variation to , or different symbol?

Tags: localization, e-commerce, woocommerce

How to replace Woocommerce `|` (pipe) separator in product variation to `,` or another character?

I use Cyrillic keyboard layout and there is no pipe symbol. To enter that symbol I have to switch to English layout, enter `|` and switch back. I have hundreds of variations of products.

Answer (score 0):

What about editing in separate text editor using your separator and then search-and-replace your separator to `|` before pasting to woocommerce?

Answer (score 0):

You should add them under **Products > Attributes** first and then just select them.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows use alt + 124 to get the | symbol (From the Numeric pad and not the top numbers)

On mac you can use alt + 7, or shift + alt + L

Usually all keyboards have this symbol as it's frequently used in programing are you sure you didn't miss it?